# razor/mvc code running on page load instead of onclick?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a loop that creates some buttons and (is meant to) make a function call when that button is pressed.

```
    foreach (Answer a in qanswers)
           {
               //Guid answerid = new Guid();
               <form method="post" action="">
               <div class="float-left">
               <input type="submit" value="@a.Answer1" class="submit" style="width:600px" onmousedown="@{saveTest(a, module, user, quest, healthsafety);}">
               <br /><br />
               </div>
               </form>
           }
```

However, it calls the "saveTest" procedure at page load for each button produced, rather than onmousedown/onmouseclick.

Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume from this that saveTest is a server side function that you are trying to call.

onmousedown is a client side event and can only directly run client side script.

If you wish to call a server side function then you will need to specify an action in the form that the page will post pack to.

Have a look here for more on this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.108).aspx

A quickly modified version of your code would be:

```
foreach (Answer a in qanswers)
{

    using (Html.BeginForm("saveTest", "ControllerName"))
    {
           <div class="float-left">
           <input type="submit" value="@a.Answer1" class="submit" style="width:600px")>
           <br /><br />
           </div>

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a server side function. This is my first web application though so my knowledge of event handling in mvc is minimal.. How would I set up a call to a function using an action?

Comment: So, your code would need to look something like what I have shown in my edits above, substituting in the name of your MVC controller.

Comment: Do I have to turn my saveTest function into an HTML helper? I have never used a controller either..

Comment: saveTest in my example is an action on a controller.  I am not sure what you mean that you have never used a controller as these are fundamental in MVC.

Comment: I understand. This is my first ever MVC application, that's why I have no knowledge of controllers. I'm using it as a self-training exercise. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The button will submit to the controller and action that has specified in the form. So please check carefully which controller and action you have specified.

```
  using (Html.BeginForm("saveTest", "Controller"))
    {
    }
```

This is the way you have to specify your form.

Regards,
Pavan.G

Comment: How do I structure the controller and saveTest as an html helper?

Comment: Just use this code before your buttons.using (Html.BeginForm("saveTest", "Controller"))
    {
    }

Comment: It doesn't recognise Html.BeginForm (had to change to Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm()) and i get this error

 Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, object)' has some invalid arguments